# How to pass a Tailwind CSS color class to a child element

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, classname

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
    const Children = ({ className }) => {
        return (
            <div className={`text-blue-400 font-sans ${className}`}>Hello world</div>
        );
    };

    const Parent = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Children className='text-red-400' />
            </div>
         )
    }
```

However, the color of the text in the `Children` component is not changing to red, but rather stays blue.

Expected result:
**the text in `Children` is red**

the actual result:
**the text in `Children` remains blue**

Comment: You are paying the class in correct way. Color blue jest overrides color red

Comment: So what are the solutions?

Comment: Conditionally render both classes. Use `clsx` library it's easier

Answer (score 2):

```
const variants = {
  red: 'text-red-400',
  blue: 'text-blue-400'
}

const Children = ({ variant = 'blue' }) => {
    return (
        <div className={`font-sans ${variants[variant]}`}>Hello world</div>
    );
};

const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Children variant='red' />
        </div>
     )
}
```

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, must all conditional css logic be performed inside the component that is rendering it?

Comment: @ecoe you just can't have multiple tailwind classes that change the same property because they will overwrite each other